# Android change Arraylist item value

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I have an ArrayList that is being read from a Text file. The array list is being displayed in a ListView. I can add and Remove items from the arraylist without an issue. I have an issue however, where the application just crashes when ever I try to modify the ArrayList. Here is the code I'm using to modify the arrayList.

```
input2 = (EditText) promptView.findViewById(R.id.userInput);
input2.setText(array.get(id).toString());
alertDialogBuilder.setCancelable(false).setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            String value2 = input2.getText().toString();
            array.set(id, value2.toString());
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
})
```

LogCat only reports an "ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException" error. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It means id is not in the bounds of the array. What is id?

Comment: Check the id value, I suppose it isn't an array index

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably mixing the id of `onClick` method and the id you use for indexes. Try renaming your id variable. Because the id in onClick method shows which dialog clicked.